# Should I be seeing a symlink to kernel in root directory?

Tags: kernel

My root shows symlinks to linux kernel are they necessary?

```
root@NAS1:/# ls -l
total 94
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Dec 15  2011 ~
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Mar 19 01:37 bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  2048 Mar 19 22:27 boot
drwxr-xr-x  23 root root  4920 Mar 19 22:31 dev
drwxr-xr-x 140 root root 12288 Mar 19 22:07 etc
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 Aug  1  2015 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    32 Mar 19 22:05 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-41-generic
drwxr-xr-x  22 root root  4096 Mar 19 01:35 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Mar 19 01:34 lib64
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    36 Jun  6  2015 libnss3.so -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss3.so
drwx------   2 root root 16384 Dec 11  2011 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x  15 root root  4096 Nov 26  2014 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul 29  2016 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Oct 10 20:42 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 206 root root     0 Mar 19 22:31 proc
drwx------  26 root root  4096 Nov 10 22:34 root
drwxr-xr-x  37 root root  1200 Mar 19 22:55 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 12288 Mar 19 01:37 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Mar 16  2012 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root     0 Mar 19 23:38 sys
drwxrwxrwt   9 root root  4096 Mar 19 23:42 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root  4096 Dec 11  2011 usr
drwxr-xr-x  16 root root  4096 Feb 14  2015 var
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    29 Mar 19 22:05 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-41-generic
```

Comment: Yes you should be seeing it...

Comment: Yes, but only when looking. If you see it without looking, then there is a problem.